# Material UI sliders React JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, rangeslider

I have three Material UI sliders showing the percentage calculation from values entered by users in 3 other textfields. I want the sum total of the percentages of three sliders to be 100. Currently on moving sliders values I am also getting negative values in textfields. My requirement is that even if a person tries to slide the slider beyond it should not move such that the total always remains 100 so that I never get negative values in textfield. Also I have been using React Hooks in this project.[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO3Tx.png)
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpz5Q.png)

Code for reference-

I am calculating the text field values in below manner-

```
const b=(bPercentage*total)/100;
const c=(cPercentage*total)/100;
const a=(total-b-c);

And percentage values for sliders accordingly-
//percentages
const aPercentage= (a/total)*100||0;
const bPercentage= (b/total)*100||0;
const cPercentage = (c/total)*100||0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Can you please update your question to include your code and what you have tried.

Comment: Hey I have included some sample code thanks :)